# FMX component not find in the library path XE6

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have created a new component in delphiXE6.

file name = eliteSoftLogFMX (component name TeliteSoftLogFMX).

I have added the component to a package and added the platform win32, Android and IOS.

I have installed the component under all 3 platform. (added library path to the component itself and 3 additional path to Android\Debug, win32\debug etc).

I created a new application and put the component on the form (from pallete).
 compiled in win32 working ok.

I switch to android platform. error.

the application is not searching (or not find) the component in the library path and is asking the file near other project files.

what can be the problem?

[DCC Fatal Error] Unit3.pas(7): F1026 File not found: 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\eliteSoftLogFMX.dcu'
 tks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is:

a) In the package options, fill "DCP output directory" and "Package output directory" and "Unit output directory" with the same path and different of the default proposed by the system.

b) The path must end with $(Platform) pattern, that says the compiler "create a different directory for each platform.

c) if your component needs any .fmx file for runtime, copy it, manually (I make this with a .cmd file) on each target directory.

Now in the program that is going to use the component,

d) you should inform the compiler, where is the compiled library. You should fill in project options the "Search path". You should put the same text that in package options has "Unit Output directory". Don't miss the use of the $(platform) pattern.

If you used .fmx files, don't miss to copy them, to the compiled directory, each time you make a change on it. Only the .fmx file, not his correspondent .pas file.